# how to create a dynamic link panel in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am very new to wordpress. I have a div for links and I want to be able to add links to that div from the wordpress admin panel. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do this with the links to the pages you create through WordPress.

You'll have to set up the page structure first, by creating each page that you want and setting the parent pages properly.

Here's where I'd start.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages